# How do I test an async axios call from a function that's defined inside an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, axios

I want test a async function that's inside a class that makes a web server call using axios and I'm getting an error saying

```
Received promise rejected instead of resolved
Rejected to value: [TypeError: errorHandler is not a function]
```

My actual code that makes the call looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default class MyClass{
   constructor(config){
      this.config = config;
   }

   async getUsers(url, params, successHandler, errorHandler) {
      return axios.post(url, params)
             .then(resp => this.handleAPIResponse.call(this, resp, successHandler, errorHandler))
             .catch(error => errorHandler);
   }
}
```

My test file looks like this

```
import MyClass from './mycode.js';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

beforeEach(() => {
  instance = new MyClass({ env: 'prod' });
});

afterEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

const mockResponseData = jest.fn((success, payload) => {
  return {
    data: {
      result: {
        success,
        payload
      }
    }
  };
});

test('should return all the users', async () => {
   const successHandler = jest.fn();
   const errorHandler = jest.fn();
   axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      data:['John Doe', 'Charles']
    });
  });

  const response = await myClass.getUsers('url', {}, successHandler, errorHandler);
  console.log(response);  // This logs undefined
  expect(successHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Also, I just want to clear it out that I've a `__mocks__` folder just under my `src` directory inside which I've a file named `axios.js` where I've mocked the every `axios` method. It looks like this:

```
export default {
  post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not have an `errorHandler` function

Comment: Where will I've to add that and how should it look like? Thanks for your help though.

Comment: First you don't have to use async as you use Promises and callback functions

Second where does the this.handleAPIResponse function come from?

third you are calling the getUsers() function without parameters you have to pass the url, params and successHandler and errorHandler

Comment: @VinayMehta did you called `jest.mock('axios')` in your test file?

Comment: @Botz Aaahh. Thank you for your first point, stupid me. As for the second one, I need one function to parse the response that I get from server, because even if the request is made with wrong arguments, the server returns a success (200) and I've to parse the response object and resolve or reject the promise accordingly. And lastly, I took care of the last one. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) explicitly says:

> When we require that module in our tests, explicitly calling `jest.mock('./moduleName')` is **required**.

so you need to call

```
jest.mock('axios')
```

in order to use your `__mocks__/axios.js`

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is what I was missing. It's fixed now. I also updated my code to look like what I've now. I've one follow up question though. Even though I'm mocking the axios call and returning mock data, I still get `undefined` when I log the response in console. Do you've any ideas on how can I test for the response `.toEqual(object)`?

Comment: @VinayMehta it's better asking it as a separate question

Comment: I created a separate post for that question. You can answer it there if you know. Here's the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416347/getting-undefined-when-i-return-some-response-from-mocked-axios-call-using-jest]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your class is using the real package, whereas your spec file uses the mocked one.

You have to mock it directly in your spec file OR in your `setupTests.js` file:

```
import axios from 'axios'

jest.spyOn(axios, 'post')
  .mockImplementationOnce(...)
```

**Edit:** maybe try calling `jest.mock('axios');` on top of your step file. It's a bit repetitive but sometimes Jest just needs this in order to mock properly.